# Cloud Functions for Firebase: admin vs root lookups

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Getting the hang of Firebase and JavaScript for coding cloud functions; but I guess I'm looking if anyone can explain the pros and cons of using the following for look-ups and/or writes in cloud functions?!

1. the use of `admin.database().ref()`
      vs
2. `root.child()`

I myself have been using `admin.database.ref()`, but do I need to? Is it just as good to use the `root.child()` instead?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I see that you've also asked this question in the comments for my [Firecast on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0). That's a good question. If you've been following along with the Cloud Functions for Firebase samples, you might have seen `admin.database().ref()`.

`admin.database().ref()` uses the [Firebase admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) to access data in the Database. As an admin reference, it has unrestricted access to any part of the Database.

In the video, `root = event.data.ref.root`, a reference to the root of the database where the `.onWrite` event occurred. ref has the same read and write access as the user who triggered the event. Unlike `admin.database().ref()`, it does not grant unrestricted access. `root.child` therefore access that specific path in the database, as long as the user has permission to access it.

Now `event.data.adminRef.root` is a Database reference with unrestricted access to any part of the Database. If this sounds like `admin.database.ref()`, it's because they're exactly alike. In my case, I chose `event.data.ref.root` to limit the amount of new topics introduced in one video. If you're more comfortable using the admin SDK, that is totally fine.

Comment: Thanks you for expanding your answer. For my app, and my point of view, using the admin.database().ref() makes sense as it allows me to have tighter security rules on the actual data, since the cloud function is governed by the me the admin. So I can have Nodes that have not write privileges except for the admin via the admin.database().ref().

Comment: Hi, Can you please look at my question regarding firebase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523615/firebase-trace-showing-wrong-median-time-latency